# CURRENT_DATE() salvando em formato diferente

Tags: php

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

No banco, a `data` está em um `varchar`, eu uso simplesmente `CURRENT_DATE()` para salvar a data no banco.

Mas parece que ele está salvando em formato diferente dentro do banco, depende do mês, algo bem esquisito.

Como salvar em um padrão definido?

`DD/MM/YYY` , por exemplo

Comment: O ideal é salvar a data como `date`(para não ter problemas com ordenação), na hora de gravar ou exibir fazer a conversão, com as funções, `date(), strtotime()` ou a classe `DateTime`.

Comment: Não deu pra entender direito. Essa função `current_time` gera uma data em PHP e você salva num campo varchar?

Comment: isso mesmo, wallace (uma correção, eu usei CURRENT_DATE())

Comment: Cara acho q o certo seria vc usar um campo do tipo `date` ou até `datetime` e usar o `now()` do `mysql` na sua query de insert

Comment: estou providenciando para mudar para o tipo data. existe alguma maneira de salva-lo em um formato determinado? fiz uma tabela de teste e criei a data de tipo date, percebi que o mysql só aceita formato YYYY-MM-DD, mas gostaria de salvar como DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: @chocolatemontana, o formato americano é padrão, o dado no banco fica em inglês, na hora de apresentar vc formata ele, vc pode fazer isso na pŕopria query: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(campo_data,'%d/%m/%Y') as 'DATA'